# What does the syntax mean in Java: new Stream<Integer>(){ ... }?

Tags: java, class, syntax, anonymous-inner-class

I have encountered the following Java syntax that I don't recognize.

This part is fine:

```
public abstract class Stream<T> implements Iterator<T> {  
   public boolean hasNext() {  
      return true; }  
   public void remove() {  
      throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Operation"); }  
}
```

But this I don't get:

```
Stream<Integer> ones = new Stream<Integer>() {  
   public Integer next() {  
      return 1; }  
};   

while(true){  
  System.out.print(ones.next() + ", ");  
}
```

What it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is providing an inline (anonymous) subclass of the `Stream` class.

Functionally, it is the same as:

```
public NewClass extends Stream {
    public Integer next() {  
       return 1; 
    }  
}
```

and

```
void someMethodInAnotherClass {
    Stream stream = new NewClass();
}
```

but as this class definition isn't used outside the method body, you can define it as anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

`ones = new Stream<Integer>() {

   public Integer next() {

      return 1; }

};`

Assigns a new instance of an anonymous implementation of `Stream<Integer>` (that contains a virtually unlimited number of `1`s. You may find more on anonymous classes in [Java In A Nutshell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is defining a Anonymous class which implements the Stream interface. To implement the interface we need to implement the method next.