# “if” statement vs OO Design - 2

Tags: java, design-patterns, if-statement

I encountered similar problem [“if” statement vs OO Design -  1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994288/if-statement-vs-oo-design) but it is slightly different. Here is the problem that open the popup (different objects/popups) onValueChange of listbox

```
Popup1 p1; // different objects
Popup2 p2; // different objects
Popup3 p3;
...

listbox.add("p1");
listbox.add("p2");
listbox.add("p3");
...

listbox.addChangeHandler() {
    if(getSelectedItem().equals("p1")){
       p1 = new Popup1();
       p1.show();
    } else if() {...}
      ....
}
```

I don't want to write "if" that if p1 then `p1 = new Popup1(); p1.center();`

How I can handle this situation? Any design-pattern?

Here is my solution but it is so costly

```
map() {

    map.put("p1", new Popup1());
    map.put("p2", new Popup2());
    map.put("p3", new Popup3()); 
}

onValueChange() {
    map.get(selectedItem).show();
}
```

One drawback is  initialization all the popups. but it is require only when valueChange

Comment: Are p1, p2, p3 truly three objects of different classes, or are they really three objects of the same class?  If they're of different classes, then I'd hope they're at least subclasses of the same base class (Popup).

Comment: @JST yes they are different classes and extend same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with leveraging the common base class when you can, but you can't always add a method to the base class for every usage that might call for selecting between different subclasses.

Your "map" solution is a decent approach for cases where the selection logic is specific to a piece of code, like matching user action to an object (e.g. popup), and you can't find a way to leverage the common base class.

> One drawback is initialization all the popups. but it is require only when valueChange

You should ***defer*** the instantiation until you need it:

```
interface Showable {
    void show();
}
map() {

    map.put("p1", new Showable() { void show() { new Popup1().show(); } } );
    map.put("p2", new Showable() { void show() { new Popup2().show(); } } );
    map.put("p3", new Showable() { void show() { new Popup3().show(); } } ); 
}

onValueChange() {
    map.get(selectedItem).show();
}
```

The anonymous classes are stateless, so if you wanted to be extra efficient, you could create the anonymous instances once and reuse them.

Comment: Yes I also did this but there lots of things in every initialization of popups. That's why, I don't init. them from start

Comment: @hilal - to be clear this code does not "init them from the start." With this code, the popup is *not* initialized *unless* that specific popup is returned from the map during the onValueChange() method.  This defers the construction/initialization of the popup *and* constructs/intitializes only the selected popup.

Comment: Note that interfaces can't be instantiated, so "new Showable()" isn't valid.

Comment: @JST - this is an anonymous class, which you can instantiate.  See, for example, the Java in a Nutshell chapter on anonymous classes - http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm - where in example 3.11 how Enumeration (an interface) is instantiated.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947708/this-appears-to-create-an-object-from-an-interface-how-does-it-work and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184052/could-anyone-please-explain-this-java-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Well, if P1 and P2 both implement the same interface, i.e

```
Popup1 implements Showable
Popup2 implements Showable
```

then you could simply do

```
Showable showable = (Showable) listbox.getSelected();
showable.show();
```

Comment: I did this but here is the problem. Showable showable is null here. then oops nulpointerexception. and you can't initialize it because they are different class different constructor

Comment: @hilal - Why can't you check for null and not try to call methods on it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this design pattern is called polymorphism. You define a super class for all your PopupX classes. In this super class you define a method "onChange". Then you realize this method in each subclass. When you select an item, you define a reference on the superclass object and call "onChange".

Comment: Hm. Ok, you can define a hashtable where you have to store each ID and a delegate-method. Then you take the ID ('p1'), determine the delegate and call this delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If there really are three different classes Popup1, Popup2, Popup3, then they should either inherit from a common base class (presumably called Popup) or implement a common interface (as already suggested).  But it appears you need a way to map strings identifying popups to popup objects.  Sounds like an opportunity for factory pattern, which would look something like this.

```
public class PopupFactory {
   private PopupFactory() { }
   public static Popup createPopup(String popupIdentifier) {
      if ("p1".equals(popupIdentifier)) return new Popup1();
      else if ("p2".equals(popupIdentifier)) return new Popup2();
      ...
   }
```

And then would be used like:

```
listbox.addChangeHandler() {
   Popup popup = PopupFactory.createPopup(getSelectedItem());
   popup.show();
   ....
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but you also write "if" but I have allergy for it. The popup count is not known. It is 9 for me now

Comment: I'm not sure why you're so anti-"if".  But you could easily use a map in the factory class instead of the conditionals.  However, you wouldn't want to map to instantiated objects, but rather to the classes themselves.  You can map "p1", for instance, to Popup1.class.  Then the body of createPopup becomes: return (Popup) map.get(popupIdentifier).newInstance();

Answer (score 0):

Your "costly" solution seems just fine to me.  Better yet, from your map you can populate the listbox, thus:

```
for (String key: map.keyset())
    listbox.add(key);
```

Of course you may want the keys in a particular order, in which case first add them to a sorted list.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(list);
for (String key: list)
    listbox.add(key);
```

Comment: Init. 10+ popup panel with many 10x(10+) widget while calling this class. Isn't it costly?

Comment: Cost of what?  Memory, speed?  Entirely negligible.  Try it and see if you can measure any difference whatsoever.  My guess is: none.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way around what you mentioned given the constraints.

If the popups are only slightly different they could be implemented as 1 class with a property that defines what type of popup you have.

Otherwise the best you can do it encapsulate it in a factory class like @JST mentioned, that way the ugly logic exists in just one place.  I'm not sure why you consider your `map` solution costly though.

If you want to dynamically invoke a constructor based on name, you're going to have to look at a dynamic language instead of Java.