# Java : Inner class of an interface (from google guice)

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

I was going through the source of google guice, and found an unfamiliar piece of code. It would be great learning if someone can clarify it.

I have very basic understanding of inner classes, as they keep the implementation details close to the public interface. Otherwise the inner class may pollute the namespace.

Now, I see the below lines [at](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/inject/Scopes.java?r=1466#42)

```
public static final Scope SINGLETON = new Scope() {
    public <T> Provider<T> scope(final Key<T> key, final Provider<T> creator) {
      return new Provider<T>() {
.........
}
```

It assign an inner class instance to the static variable, but Scope is an interface defined as ([at](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/inject/Scope.java?r=1466#32))

public interface Scope

> Part 1:

Is it possible to instantiate the interface?? or is it a succinct syntax for an anonymous implementation of an interface??

> Part 2:

If anyone can explain what the author is intended by multiple nested classes above (Scope and Provider), and why it make sense to implement this way, it would help me to understand. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This appears to create an object from an interface; how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947708/this-appears-to-create-an-object-from-an-interface-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @Bert, agreed, this question is not specific to guice, it is a generic Java question.

Comment: @Mike - good eyes - tags updated for future searchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The {}-block after creates an anonymous inner class which implements the interface given.

Frequently seen with `Runnable` too.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, that validate my assumption. can you give some pointer to part, which I marked correctly in the qn. thanks again for ur time.

Comment: Seen by the compiler after the invocation it is a `Scope`and you can only use it as such, since it cannot be cast to anything else (remember it doesn't have a name you can use).  The reason for this is simply that you want a Scope that returns a Provider and the author did not see any reason for giving either of these a named implementation.  Probably due to it being simple.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to instantiate the interface? or is it a succinct syntax for an anonymous implementation of an interface?

Yup and yup.

[This appears to create an object from an interface; how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947708/this-appears-to-create-an-object-from-an-interface-how-does-it-work)

[What does the syntax mean in Java: new Stream<Integer>(){ ... }?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184052/could-anyone-please-explain-this-java-syntax)

Example 3.11 instantiates the Enumeration interface in http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

```
public java.util.Enumeration enumerate() {
  // The anonymous class is defined as part of the return statement
  return new java.util.Enumeration() { 
      ....
  };  // Note the required semicolon: it terminates the return statement
}
```

> If anyone can explain what the author is intended by multiple nested classes above

Nothing special about nesting - both are anonymous classes and use an anonymous class for the same reason you use anonymous classes anywhere else: when you have a single-use implementation for an interface or subclass, i.e. you have no reason to separate definition/implementation from use.